# Keep encoded tag in XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I would like to modify a large XML file using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

When using handler callbacks, `XML::Twig` seems to change characters that are encoded as HTML entities such as the greater than sign (`&gt;` -- `>`).

Example script:

```perl
my $input = q~
<root>
    <p>&lt;encoded tag&gt;</p>
</root>
~;

my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    keep_spaces              => 1,
    twig_roots               => { 'p' => \&convert, },   # process p tags
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,                       # print the rest
);

$t->parse($input);


sub convert {
    my ($t, $p)= @_;

    $p->set_att('x' => 'y');

    $p->print;
}
```

This will turn the document into the following:

```xml
<root>
    <p x="y">&lt;encoded tag></p>
</root>
```

I was expecting to get this:

```xml
<root>
    <p x="y">&lt;encoded tag&gt;</p>
</root>
```

How do I keep the encoded contents of tags using `XML::Twig`?

Comment: `XML::Twig` has left the closing bracket unencoded because it is not ambiguous at that point in the data, and any decent XML parser will accept it happily. Do you need to provide for an "indecent" one?!

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't sure about the target parser. I just confirmed it, it's a decent parser. While testing, I simply noticed the behavior and it was unexpected.
I'm curious, it there a way to provide the content for "indecent" parsers?

Comment: I'm looking at it and will let you know when I've absorbed the relevant module code. The module's author is regularly on this site, and he may well give you an answer before the day is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either set the `keep_encoding` option in the constructor, as below, or call `$twig->set_keep_encoding($option)` to modify it after the construction of the object

Note that [the module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) says this about it

> This is a (slightly?) evil option: if the XML document is not UTF-8 encoded and you want to keep it that way, then setting keep_encoding will use the "Expat" `original_string` method for character, thus keeping the original encoding, as well as the original entities in the strings.

But here it is, doing as you asked. The risk is your own call

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Twig;

my $input = <<END_XML;
<root>
    <p>&lt;encoded tag&gt;</p>
</root>
END_XML

my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    keep_spaces              => 1,
    keep_encoding            => 1,
    twig_roots               => { p => \&convert },   # process p elements
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,                    # print the rest
);

$t->parse($input);


sub convert {
    my ($t, $p) = @_;
    $p->print;
}
```

#### output

```xml
<root>
    <p>&lt;encoded tag&gt;</p>
</root>
```